# tools to generator field constant string in java?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, lombok

I need a Eclipse or IDEA plugin to generate field name constant string in java. For example, in ORM we often define a class Like this:

```
class DealDB {
    public String dealId;
}
```

We can generate get and set method with eclipse or IDEA, but we cannot generate field name constant string. When we write query code in java, we often need this constant string.

```
class DealDB {
    public String dealId;

    // to generate this
    public static final String FIELD_DEALID="dealId";
}
```

Maybe extend lombok (https://projectlombok.org/) can implement this.

Comment: You may define your own template for this one, in Eclipse at least.

Comment: I would strongly discourage you to use such constants. It will make your code much harder to read. Example: "`select d from Deal d where d.dealId = :dealId"` is much clearer than `"select d from Deal d where d." + Deal.FIELD_DEALID + " = :dealId"`. And the more you'll use such constants, the worse it will become. Use unit tests to ensure your queries are correct, and do the right thing.

Comment: @JBNizet we use morphia to query mongodb, we ofter write the code like `Query<DealDB> query = datastore.createQuery(DealDB.class);
query.field("created").greaterThanOrEq(12345);`, so after replace "created" with const field string, we can write code more effectively, and can easily search which code use this field.

Comment: While it may allow you to use IDE tools to find usages and so forth, it's not a great plan. Proper design would make sure that you don't need to search for usages, since all access would be done in a single package for example.

Comment: @FieldNameConstants - This is the class level Lombok query that does the job. It will create a class called Field and generate fields names as constants inside it. 

Ref: https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/FieldNameConstants

Answer (score 2):

In IntelliJ, I can suggest something that is not exactly what you are asking for, but it comes close.

Take the following code sample, containing the String `"dealId"`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("dealId");
}
```

Position the cursor on `"dealId"` and hit *Ctrl - Alt - C* (refactor: Create Constant).

IntelliJ will pop up with a dialog and then create the following for you:

```
    public static final String DEAL_ID = "dealId";
```

You also have option to "Replace all occurences" and "Move to another class".